# how to read the data from the binary file and create lists in c?

Tags: c

I am trying to read a binary file which it has names,years, from movies and then to create a list from that file data....but when am using this code am getting a blank screen.

```
struct node *next;
    }node;
    node *head;
    node *tail;
     node*inventory = NULL;
    int main(int argc , char * argv){
        node *current;
        node n;
        node *p;
    FILE *ptr;
    ptr=fopen("movies.dat", "rb");
    head= NULL;
    while(!feof(ptr))
    {
        p = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (!head)
        {
            head =(node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
            current = head;
        }
        fread(p, sizeof(node), 1, ptr);
       current->next = p;
        p=current;
    }
    fclose(ptr);
```

The example output should look like this:

```
$ ./a.out --list-all
       The Godfather       1972         245066416.00
              Snatch       2000          30093108.00
```

Thanks in regards

Comment: I don't see any code that writes anything.  Debug tip: first just prove you can read a few bytes and write them.

Comment: i have also that part in my code that i can write on the file but i am just not sure if my fread is correct.... FILE *write_ptr;
write_ptr=fopen("movies.dat","wb");
fseek(write_ptr,0,SEEK_END);
fwrite(p,sizeof(node),1,write_ptr);
fclose(write_ptr);

Comment: Please don't put this code into comments, but putit in the question. You should at least provide some complete function, not only snippets without context.

Comment: Debug tip:  before any processing, prove you can read and write by simply echoing the contents of the input file into the output.

Comment: First of all , where is the List?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all a list should look like this
Inside the header file :

```
typedef struct Node_t Node;

struct Node_t
{
    void* data;
    int id;
    Node_t* next_node; //next node
};

typedef struct List_t
{
    int number_of_nodes;
    Node_t* start_index;  //pointer , points at first node , start of the list.
}List;
```

So upon reading (which seems ok) , for each movie you have to create a structure to hold movie data.Let's say

```
typedef struct Movie_t
{
    char name[16];
    int year;
}Movie_t;
```

So in every element you read you store name and year in a struct and then you create a Node_t that points for void* data in the pointer of the Movie_t object and you add Node_t in list.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not enough to help you where exactly you made the mistake. Hence I have developed the below codes for you. Just modify the structure for more field and change the code accordingly so that you can learn properly.

```
    struct Movie
    {
            char  *name;
            char  *date;
            struct Movie *next;
    };

    struct Movie * initialize(char *);
    void display(struct Movie *);

    int main()
    {
            struct Movie *head;
            char fname[100];
            head=initialize("movies.dat");
            display(head);
    }

    struct Movie * initialize(char *fname)
    {
            FILE* fpointer;
            char ch;
            fpointer = fopen(fname,"r");
            if(fpointer == NULL)
            {

                    printf("\nFile not found");
                    exit(1);
            }

            //FILE IS OPENED
            struct Movie *head=NULL;
            struct Movie *t;
            char line[255];
            char sent[2]=";";

            while(!feof(fpointer) && fgets(line,sizeof line,fpointer))
            {
                char *name=strtok(line,sent);
                char *date=strtok(NULL,sent);
                    if(head == NULL)
                    {
                              head=(struct Movie*)malloc(sizeof(struct Movie));
                              t = head;
                              t->name = (char *)malloc(strlen(name));
                              t->date = (char *)malloc(strlen(date));
                              strcpy(t->name,name);
                              strcpy(t->date,date);
                              t->next=NULL;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            t->next=(struct Movie*)malloc(sizeof(struct Movie));
                            t=t->next;
                            t->name = (char *)malloc(strlen(name));
                            t->date = (char *)malloc(strlen(date));
                            strcpy(t->name,name);
                            strcpy(t->date,date);
                            t->next=NULL;
                    }
            }
            return head;
    }

    void display(struct Movie *h)
    {
            while(h!=NULL)
            {
                    printf("Name :%20s        %10s\n",h->name,h->date);
                    h=h->next;
            }
    }
```

now create movies.dat with below information:-

The Godfather;1972;
Snatch;2000;

here in the file you can add as many as film information. Here every field has been separated by `;` you can separate field with any special character as per your wish but you need to make necessary changes in the below line of code each time.

```
 char sent[2]=";";
```

Your field separator can be any character for example  `The Godfather|1972|` in this case you need to modify your code like `char sent[2]="|";` Better give it a proper name like `char seperator[2]=":";` here your separator is `:`

Also do not forget to add header files , and

Wish you all the very best.